# DOS6.22 load config.sys manually

Tags: ms-dos

Is there a way to load config.sys manually after DOS is already booted?
Autoexec.bat can be run any time that is no problem.

Comment: I dont think it will work without a reboot... I havent used DOS in so long though...

Answer (score 4):

No. Config.sys is the config file that is used to define how MS-DOS is loaded. It defines things like memory and is being loaded while MS-DOS boots before it starts things like the memory management.

A reboot is required to reload config.sys.

Answer (score 0):

Some things in config.sys reorganise memory at quite a low level, like the loading of HIMEM.SYS can't be run afterwards, and  the loading of EMM386.EXE [NOEMS /RAM..] line in config.sys can't be run afterwards.

But, some other lines could be loaded afterwards, where/(in the rare case that!) somebody had written a program to,  for example if you wanted to change the colour and certain features of the command prompt with ANSI escape codes, you'd have to load ANSI.SYS   You could load ANSI.SYS in config.sys, but alternatively, there was a program ANSI.EXE which you could run afterwards instead of loading ANSI.SYS in config.sys. And of course no restart is required to run ANSI.EXE!

There was a program I once saw called config.exe but I don't think it does it.